# Umbraco 7 using runtime cache

Tags: umbraco7

I would like to store a small number of text strings in the runtime cache

```
using Umbraco.Core.CacheHelper
```

ie

```
ApplicationContext.Current.ApplicationCache.Runtime
```

but after searching, I am not 100% clear on how to get and to set values - can anyone supply an example.

I think I can use get to also set values but how would I update them once set?

I have tried

```
ApplicationContext.ApplicationCache.RuntimeCache.InsertCacheItem<runtimeCache>("myObject",rC);
```

where I have created a class myObject and and instance rC but this crashes

Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Umbraco.Core.ApplicationContext.ApplicationCache.get'

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to work on an instance such as:

`ApplicationContext.Current.ApplicationCache.RuntimeCache.GetCacheItem("Key")`

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but this is how I set it up:

You need (2) methods. One to be the endpoint (whether it be an API endpoint, Action, etc). The second method is what the caching implementation is going to call, only if the `key` isn't in the cache already, and/or (if set) the timeout has passed.

Your cache keys need to be unique, based on what you're requesting. If you are caching, for example, product information, not naming your keys the different would give you bad data, since it would always give you "Product 101".

```
public static List<ProductCategoryModel> GetPopularProducts(IPublishedContent homePage)
{
    TimeSpan cacheLifetime = TimeSpan.MinValue;
    TimeSpan.TryParse("06:00:00", out cacheLifetime);
    var cachedItem = ApplicationContext.Current.ApplicationCache.RuntimeCache.GetCacheItem($"GetPopularProducts", () => GetProductCategoryData(homePage.Descendants("Product").Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("popularProduct")).OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdateDate).Take(15).ToList(), true), cacheLifetime);
    return cachedItem as List<ProductCategoryModel>;
}
```

On the 3rd line inside the method, `var cachedItem = .....`, the first param of the `GetCacheItem` is the key name. In this case, "GetPopularProducts". The 2nd param calls the 2nd method that I was explaining above, and the third param is our cache "lifetime".

```
public static List<ProductCategoryModel> GetProductCategoryData(List<IPublishedContent> umbProductCategories, bool isProductTiles)
{ ....... // return some data }
```

When you call the `GetPopularProducts` method, you don't have to "add to" the cache. This variation of the method both adds "to the cache" and retrieves, based on our "key" (if saved and found in the cache) passed into `GetCacheItem`.